# __autoreleasing in error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I noticed this pattern in Apple functions which return errors

```
error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError
```

I understand the meaning, that it's pointer to pointer, used to carry out the result (using just * would change only the local copied variable, but not the outside one) but I'm concerned about the:

> __autoreleasing

**What happens if I leave it out? Do I get a leak? Why is it necessary?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to explicitly specify `__autoreleasing` when defining a function that
returns an object, for example

```
-(BOOL)doSomething:(NSError **)error;
```

The ARC compiler automatically inserts the `__autoreleasing`. This is explained in
the [Clang/ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#indirect-parameters) documentation:

> 4.4.2 Indirect parameters
>
> If a function or method parameter has type T*, where T is an
>   ownership-unqualified retainable object pointer type, then:
>
> - if T is const-qualified or Class, then it is implicitly qualified with
>     __unsafe_unretained;
> - otherwise, it is implicitly qualified with __autoreleasing.

The Xcode code completion
also knows about that and displays `(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error`.

---

When *calling* such a function the ARC compiler also automatically does 
"the right thing", so you can just call

```
NSError *error;
BOOL success = [self doSomething:&error];
```

As explained in the ["Transitioning to ARC Release Notes"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), the compiler inserts a temporary
`__autoreleasing` variable:

```
NSError *error;
NSError * __autoreleasing tmp = error;
BOOL success = [self doSomething:&tmp];
error = tmp;
```

(For the gory details you can read 4.3.4 "Passing to an out parameter by writeback" in
the Clang/ARC documentation.)